# How to define different firewall rules for different users on the same machine running on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, firewalls

Provided that one machine running on Windows 7, connected to LAN, and connected to the Internet via a gateway in the LAN. There are two logon user accounts A and B on the machine. I want:

1, User A can access the LAN but except the Internet;

2, User B can access the Internet but except the LAN.

How to define different firewall rules for A and B to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're going to have to tell us which firewall you are using and where it is sitting.

Comment: I'm using the built-in firewall of Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the stock windows firewall, then this cannot be done. The firewall is machine-based, not user-based.

To have the control you want, you need to install a different firewall.

Comment: You can, I think, use GPO to dynamically reconfigure the built-in firewall based on who logs on, but of course that introduces much more complexity into the network than installing a "proper" firewall.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you're not exactly trying to scale, then you could write some quick rules in [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) to accomplish what you need.